# Get the "padding" around a control

Tags: c++, winapi, size, controls

I use win32 to generate my interface.

I'm looking to get the padding that windows naturally puts around controls. For example, in a tabcontrol the height of the tabcontrol includes the height of the border at the top and the height of the tab headers at the top. Same goes for buttons.

I'd like to know how I can find the exact height of these extra paddings before I create the actual control, as I need to add them to the height and width so that the client area of the control is the right size after creation to host content which has a static exact size.

Comment: No guarantee, but I'd start by looking at `GetSystemMetrics` with things like `SM_CXBORDER`.

Comment: Took a look but unfortunately it's only good for windows and not controls.

Comment: Most controls (e.g., buttons) *are* windows. Not *certain* about tab controls, but my immediate guess would be that they are too.

Comment: What I actually meant was that it'll only return the window frame size which isn't applicable on things like buttons, tab controls, etc

Comment: Is it possible that the difference between `GetWindowRect` and `GetClientRect` would just be the border?

Comment: @chris I thought about doing that, but I need to calculate it before the control is created. I've looked at GetThemeBackgroundContentRect for finding sizing but I'm unsure how to use it. Maybe someone can explain how it works?

Comment: @kvanberendonck, Before, right :/ Maybe you could create them, do that, and use `AdjustWindowRect`? Creating them hidden and showing later is fine if you don't want any chance of the user seeing flicker.

Comment: AdjustWindowRect is perfect! Thanks !

Comment: @kvanberendonck, If that works fine, I'll wait a bit see if a more elegant solution comes along.

Comment: @kvanberendonck, LOL I didn't even realize `AdjustWindowRect` doesn't actually *do* anything to any window. I have a strange deja vu that I've discovered this before. That would be the elegant solution I was talking about. Replace my strategy with `SetWindowPos` then. I think it would be best to just answer your own question with what you did.

Comment: @kvanberendonck The "padding" is nothing to do with Windows in general, but is something specific to each control. You'll need to find find a way of correctly asking each window you're interested in. Note that the tab controls tend to use a standard value accross all styles/versions.

Comment: In the end I used the control specific AdjustRect messages to adjust a rect containing the size of the control to the right size. For example, in the tab control I used TabCtrl_AdjustRect(..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to `AdjustWindowRect` for adjusting windows for padding.